# Navigate to vscode definition by clicking react component in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, browser

Is it possible e.g. using a plugin to navigate to a react component in vscode by (right-)clicking the component in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is that the js your browser reads is already past compilation by either CRA build script or WebPack hence it's difficult to map it back to the raw code in vscode.

Comment: Sourcemaps already solved this part of the problem.